# How to delete old files with Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm writing a function for Firebase Cloud Functions in which I can delete old nodes from Firebase Database. On each of these nodes is a link to a file saved in Firebase Storage.

Database Structure

```
  "data" : {
    "-Lo0onTCSVeY-Kco5ujX" : {
      "photo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0...",
      "idD" : "-Lo0onTCSVeY-Kco5ujX",
      "idUs" : "jh4Ch9rBgQPwBTfv43MgNissRUP2",
      "timestamp" : 1567693686925,
    }
  },
```

Function:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var DAY_MILLIS = 86400000 //1 Day

exports.deleteOldPosts = functions.database.ref('/data/{pushId}').onWrite(function(change) {
    var ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    var now = Date.now();
    var cutoff = now - DAY_MILLIS;
    var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      // create a map with all children that need to be removed
      var updates = {};
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        updates[child.key] = null;
      });
      // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
      return ref.update(updates);
    });
});
```

How can I do to delete the file too?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future, it will be much easier to delete a file if you know its path in Cloud Storage.  What you have now is a download URL, which does not easily translate to a path when using backend SDKs.  If you have a path, all you have to do is feed that to the Cloud Storage node SDK to delete it.

Comment: Do you want to delete all file older than a date?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(ref.update(updates));
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
promises.push(bucket.file(`file/${anotherFile}`).delete());
return Promise.all(promises);
```